# fullcalendar month view allow selectoverlap and eventoverloap only for start and end date

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I need your help.
Is there any way to allow selectOverlap and eventOverlap just for start date and end date when an event has more days?

Sorry for my english

Thanks

Comment: can you please provide some more details about the task

Comment: in fullcalendar I need a way to allow me to create a new event  using only the last day of an existing event and the future dates